# How do I compile Minix source code?

Tags: makefile, minix

I intend to make modifications to the Minix kernel. But before I start, I want to compile it, so that I know any further compilation issues are caused by things that I did.

I have obtained the [Minix 3 source code from github](https://github.com/minix3/minix), where it is mirrored:

```
git clone git://github.com/minix3/minix
```

Now, I wish to compile it before making any modifications to the code. When I do `make` in `src`, I get the message

```
Makefile:109: *** missing separator.  Stop.
```

I tried compiling just the kernel by doing `make` in `src/minix/kernel`. In this case, I get the message

```
Makefile:2: *** missing separator.  Stop.
```

How do I circumvent this problem? How do I compile the Minix source?

Comment: Please add a link to the github mirror.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you want that isn't in the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Minix building procedure is different. Please read through [Crosscompiling MINIX with build.sh](http://wiki.minix3.org/doku.php?id=developersguide:crosscompiling) and [MinixOnARM](http://wiki.minix3.org/doku.php?id=developersguide:minixonarm) before trying anything. The Makefile under minix/kernel is not designed in normal as to compile with a simple `make` command. check if you are able to compile with `build.sh` tool at the `minix/` folder

Answer (score 1):

This is how I do it:  After logging in as root I navigate to /usr/src/tools and type in "make new fresh" (no quotations).  It then compiles.

If you've made changes and you want Minix to boot to that new image, then do the following:  After it finishing compiling it will say "Done."  Then type in "shutdown -h now".  Then at the next prompt type in "exit".  It will then start to reboot.  Hit "3" and then Minix will boot to that custom boot image you just made when you did the "make new fresh."